# IMemoryCache in Scoped Service

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a scoped service that I'm looking to inject IMemoryCache into.

IMemoryCache has been added during startup using the following code:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Autofac is configured in Program.cs as follows:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                        {
                            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                        });
```

I have another class, UserService which I'd like to access cached data with but I'm running into problems with DI. I should add I'm using AutoFac but have also tried switching this off and get the same result:

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
> 'Rostering.Infrastructure.Identity.Services.UserService'
> can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache memoryCache' of constructor 'Void
> .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache)'.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be?

Comment: Could you share more details how do you set up Autofac?

Comment: @user2250152 I've added details of how autofac is configured

Comment: The services you show getting wired up in Autofac are not the services you're showing as being resolved in the exception. `AuthenticatedUserService` is neither `IUserService` nor `UserService`, even though the names look similar.

Comment: @TravisIllig my mistake, that was just the old name for the class, I've amended them and can assure you they both match.

Comment: Fair enough. Details are important in these things - lots of answers actually are because the person is resolving or registering the wrong type. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Autofac:

```
public interface IUserService
{
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public UserService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    // autofac container builder
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MemoryCache>().As<IMemoryCache>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsManager<>)).As(typeof(IOptions<>)).SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsManager<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsMonitor<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsMonitor<>)).SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsFactory<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsFactory<>));
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsCache<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsMonitorCache<>)).SingleInstance();

    var container = builder.Build();
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var us = scope.Resolve<IUserService>();
    }
}
```

I've registered `IMemoryCache` as `SingleInstance` and `IOptions<>` because `MemoryCache` depends on it.

Comment: This is really close to working. my userService now resolves perfectly but anything that injects that service can no longer locate it's dependency.